# json rendering issue in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I have added following code in user.rb.

```
def as_json(options={})
  h = super(:only => [:id, :content, :created_at, :updated_at])
  h
end
```

But in another api I have to get username and address as well. But producing these four fields when rendering json. How can I get both outputs. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let the two API be

this API should return username and address too

```
def api1
  User.first.as_json(user_info: true)
end
```

this does not need to return username and address

```
def api2
  User.first.as_json(user_info: false)
end
```

let the user.rb be

```
 class User < ApplicationRecord
   def as_json(options = {})

     if options[:user_info] == true
       user = super(:only => [:id, :content, :created_at, :updated_at, :username, :address])
     else 
       user = super(:only => [:id, :content, :created_at, :updated_at])
     end 
     user
   end 
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any better idea but I think you can use `except` like:

```
def as_json(options={})
  h = super(:only => [:id, :content, :created_at, :updated_at, :username, :address])
  h
end
```

Then when rendering you can use `@yourVariable.as_json(except: [:username, :address])` when you don't need those or you can use `only` instead of `except`